# Sql Server Data Type of a List Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, list, type-conversion

I am currently designing tables for my database. I am having a hard time, since I am just a beginner in VB.Net, to figure it out on how I can store multiple data just like a list in my table. The situation is like this, the system is a Daily Field Report Log. In a particular service request, the number of plumbers will varied. Sometimes in a particular service request there will be two or three plumbers, sometimes only one plumber or more than five plumbers.

Any help or suggestion to this matter is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Design two tables for log and plumbers with primary key foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I might have create three diff tables

1st Table is ServiceInfo

```
ServiceID
ServiceName
OtherServiceInfoColumns
```

2nd Table PlumberInfo

```
PlumberID
PlumberName
OtherPlumbersInfoColumns
```

3rd Table ServicePlumber

```
ServicePlumberID
ServiceID
PlumberID
```

And when you need info i would have created this query

```
Select S.ServiceName , P.PlumberName, S.OtherServiceInfoColumns , 
P.OtherPlumbersInfoColumns from 
ServiceInfo S Inner Join ServicePlumber SP on SP.ServiceID = S.ServiceID
PlumberInfo P Inner Join ServicePlumber SP on SP.ServiceID = P.PlumberID
```

Comment: Move the joins into the From statement thus making it ANSI SQL 92 compliant.  Also you can drop the ServicePlumberID in the ServicePlumber table.  The combination of ServiceId and PlumberID make the record unique as long as they are defined as PKs.

Comment: for joins i changed the query but for ServicePlumberID , I think it is good to let it be der.